# Codeigniter - using set_value() to populate a form for editing (with no POST involved)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a view containing a form. with input fields and radio buttons. This form needs to be populated with the data from database, so as to use it as an data editing form.

I have used the set_value() function for the form validation where the view is called from the same controller after the post. **But how to use set_value function with out a POST? i.e. simply populate the values in a form in the view that's loaded**. with say, an Array or object from database.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use it like this

```
set_value('myfield', isset($databaseData['myfield']) ? $databaseData['myfield'] : '');
```

`$databaseData` will contain the data from the database which you have loaded in the controller and passed to view

```
$data['databaseData']= $this->my_model->find($parameters);

$this->load->view('myformview',$data);
```

Comment: Can you do this and also still have it work with $_POST?

Comment: Thank you very much man. i tried ajax and that also didnt work. your answer was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

You try this code

```
set_value('<field_name>', @$field_from_db);
```

`@` is used to skipps errors if field is not set

Comment: Thanks for the Info about using @

Comment: Thanks everyone for pointing out to the use of @. I looked everywhere. I think this approach is a lot better than @dianuj's. Even in codeigniter core code uses the set_value with the @.